# How to check if userID from req.user from Passport JS and MongdoDB userID match before update/delete document?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am making a voting app with a `delete and edit` function for user who are authenticated using `Passport JS` + the specific poll belongs to him/her.

I have the following `Passport setup` with `Node/Express`:

```
 passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({ 

  clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: CALLBACK_URL

}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done){  
//callback function after login  

  process.nextTick(function(){        
    done(null, profile);        
  });      
}));


passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){

req.session.passport.user = {};  

  done(null, user);

});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){

  done(null, id);

});


app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));


app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/error'

}));

app.get('/success', function(req, res, next) { 

  res.send('Successfully logged in. You can close this window');      
});


app.get('/error', function(req, res, next) {    
  res.send("Error logging in.");      
});
```

**So, every request now has the user attached to it (req.user) with the id and displayName**

I use the following middle ware function to secure a route server side:

```
var auth = function(req,res,next){

    if(!req.isAuthenticated()){

      console.log("You need to login!");

      res.sendStatus(401);                    
    } 
    else {

      console.log("User is logged in, success!");          
      next();          
    }              
};
```

Polls are saved in the following format in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57c69ec65ed24f166b4e98cf"
    },
    "title": "Poll Test",
    "options": [
        {
            "option": "Option1",
            "votes": 0
        },
        {
            "option": "Option2",
            "votes": 0
        },
        {
            "option": "Option3",
            "votes": 0
        },
        {
            "option": "Option4",
            "votes": 0
        }
    ],
    "userID": "1798846357",
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "date": "Wed Aug 31 2016 09:09:26 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
}
```

I want to protect the following route from my REST API, that is used by for example a `delete poll` function in the front-end.

The problem is that it checks if a user is authenticated, but not if the poll belongs to the user. In other words: not if the `userID` in the request and the `userID` in the database match.

I try to put an if statement inside the `db.collection` function to check if `req.user.id and doc.data.id match` but it's not working.

I think that is because the updateOne has already been done.

How can I retrieve the poll with the userID and then check that with the req.user.id and if match, continue with the update?

```
    app.delete("/polls/:id", auth, function(req, res) {         
    db.collection(POLLS_COLLECTION).deleteOne({
      _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)
    }, function(err, doc) {

      if (err) {

        handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to delete contact");

      } else {

        res.status(204).end();
      }    
    });        
  });        
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

Answer to the question

> `How can I retrieve the poll with the userID and then check that with the req.user.id and if match, continue with the update?`

```
db.collectionName.updateOne({userID :  req.user.id}, {updateQuery});
```

The above query will update the document, if there is any document present with `userID` same as value `req.user.id`. Else there won't be any update.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Check with the `filter` parameter of `deleteOne` or `updateOne`:

```
db.collection(POLLS_COLLECTION).deleteOne({
      _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id),
      userID: req.user._id,
    }, function(err, doc) {
    …
    });
  });
```

You also could first fetch your vote object and use `.then` on that query to delete only if the condition matches, but in that case you open yourself up to concurrency problems without write locks. (someone could change the userID of the vote Object while you're checking if the vote belongs to that user – what will you do then?)